# Java/Linux cert exception

Tags: java, linux

I'm running an osgi-application locally in Eclipse. When I did it using windows it worked fine, it'a server/client setup.

I later installed Fedora 17 and tried doing the same thing, the server seems to be working fine but when I try to connect using the client I get the following error:

```
java.security.cert.certpathvalidatorexception no subject alternative dns name matching localhost found
```

I have tried googling the problem but I didn't find any silver bullets.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the few useful pages I stumbled upon: http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/no_subject_alternative_names_matching

Comment: That looks like a good description of your problem. Have you tried the solution? What problems did you find with that?

Comment: In the end I checked my /etc/hosts, it looked fine, I changed the URL I was connecting to and it worked. I still have no idea how exactly but I'm just happy it works.